# Build a C-like interpreter Using Scala

Tags: c, scala

I need to implement C-like interpreter. Here are grammars.

```
Program ::= Commandlist
Commandlist ::= Command | Command; Commandlist;
Command ::= Left = Expression | while Expression : Commandlist end | print Left
Expression ::= Number | (Expression1 + Expression2) | (Expression1 - Expression2) | Left | &Left
Left ::= Variable | *Left
Number ::= string of digits
Variable ::= string of letters
```

Here are the operator trees the interpreter uses.

```
PTREE ::= [ CTREE+ ]
CTREE ::= Assign(LTREE, ETREE) | While(ETREE, CLIST) | Print(LTREE)
ETREE ::= Num(String) | Add(ETREE, ETREE) | Sub(ETREE, ETREE) | At(LTREE) | Amph(LTREE)
LTREE ::= Var(String) | Star(LTREE)
```

Here are the codes for implementing C-like interpreter.

```
trait OpTree {
  sealed abstract class Ltree
  case class Var(x: String) extends Ltree
  case class Star(l: Ltree) extends Ltree

  sealed abstract class Etree
  case class Num(s: String) extends Etree
  case class Add(e1: Etree, e2: Etree) extends Etree
  case class Sub(e1: Etree, e2: Etree) extends Etree
  case At(l: Ltree) extends Etree
  case Amph(l: Ltree) extends Etree

  sealed abstract class Ctree
  case class Assign(l: Ltree, e: Etree) extends Ctree
  case class While(e: Etree, c: List[Ctree]) extends Ctree
  case class Print(l: Ltree) extends Ctree
}

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

object MiniC extends JavaTokenParsers with OpTree {
  def parse(source: String): List[Ctree] = 
    parseAll(prog, source) match {
    case Success(optree,_) => optree
    case _ => throw new Exception("Parse error!")
  }
  def prog: Parser[List[Ctree]] = commlist
  def commlist: Parser[List[Ctree]] = rep1sep(comm, ";")
  def comm: Parser[Ctree] = left~("="~>expr) ^^
                            { case l~e => Assign(l, e) } |
                            "print"~>left ^^
                            { case l => Print(l) } |
                            ("while"~>expr<~":")~(commlist<~"end") ^^
                            { case e~cs => While(e, cs) }
  def expr: Parser[Etree] = wholeNumber ^^ (Num(_)) |
                            "("~>expr~op<~expr")" ^^
                            { case e1~"+"~e2 => Add(e1, e2)
                              case e1~"-"~e2 => Sub(e1, e2) } |
                              left ^^ (At(_)) |
                             "&"~>left ^^ (Amph(_))
  def left: Parser[Ltree] = ident ^^ (Var(_)) |
                            "*"~>left ^^ (Star(_))
  def op: Parser[String] = "+" | "-"

  //Interpreter
  val memory = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int]
  var env = Map.empty[String, Int]
  def interpretPTREE(p: List[Ctree]): Unit = interpretCLIST(p)
  def interpretCLIST(cs: List[Ctree]): Unit = 
    for(c <- cs) yield interpretCTREE(c)
  def interpretCTREE(c: Ctree): Unit = c match {
    case Assign(l, e) => env + (interpretLTREE(l).toString -> interpretETREE(e))
    case Print(l) =>
      if(env.contains(interpretLTREE(l).toString)) println(env(interpretLTREE(l).toString))
      else throw new Exception("Error: " + l + " is undefined.")
      env
    case While(e, cs) =>
      if (interpretETREE(e) != 0)
        interpretCTREE(c)
      else env
  }
  def interpretETREE(e: Etree): Int = e match {
    case Num(s) => s.toInt
    case Add(e1, e2) => interpretETREE(e1) + interpretETREE(e2)
    case Sub(e1, e2) => interpretETREE(e1) - interpretETREE(e2)
    case At(l) => interpretLTREE(l)
    case Amph(l) => interpretLTREE(l)
  }
  def interpretLTREE(l: Ltree): Int = l match {
    case Var(x) => if (env.contains(x)) env(x)
                   else throw new Exception("Error: " + x + " is undefined.")
    case Star(l) => if (memory.contains(l)) memory(interpretLTREE(l))
                    else throw new Exception("Error: " + l + " is undefined.")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {
      val source = args(0)
      println("input : " + source)
      val optree = parse(source)
      println("optree : " + optree)
      interpretPTREE(optree)
      println("final memory : " + memory)
      println("final namespace : " + env)
    }
    catch { case e: Exception => println(e)}
  }
}
```

The ambiguous parts of this program are definition part of the interpretCTREE, the interpretETREE, and the interpretLTREE. If I run this program with arguments of

```
y = 4; z = &y; x = (7 + *z); *z = (y + 1)
```

the program result of optree should look like this:

```
List(Assign(Var("x"),Num("4")), 
     Assign(Var("z"),Amph(Var("y"))), 
     Assign(Var("x"),Add(Num("7"),Star(Var("z")))), 
     Assign(Star(Var("z")),Add(Var("y"),Num("1"))))
```

However, I have a result looked like this:

```
List(Assign(Var("x"),Num("4")), 
     Assign(Var("z"),Amph(Var("y"))), 
     Assign(Var("x"),Add(Num("7"),At(Star(Var("z"))))), 
     Assign(Star(Var("z")),Add(At(Var("y")),Num("1"))))
```

Plus, I want to see the value of the memory, and env, but result contains error message.

```
java.lang.Exception: Error: y is undefined.
```

So, how can I fix this to get right optree, final value of the memory, and env??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (once obvious code errors are fixed) seems to lie here

```
def interpretCTREE(c: Ctree): Unit = c match {
    case Assign(l, e) => env + (interpretLTREE(l).toString -> interpretETREE(e))
    /* ... */
```

Depending on whether `l` is `Var(x)` or `Star(l)`, this should behave differently.

If `l` is `Var(x)`, then, if the environment does not contain `x`, a new memory location should be created, the environment should be updated accordingly, and then the value `interpretETREE(e)` should be stored at this location.

If `l` is `Star(l)`, then `l` should be evaluated and the value `interpretETREE(e)` should be stored at the memory location obtained by this evaluation.

Also, it seems to me like the optree created by the program is correct, whereas the first one you mention (the "should look like this" one) does not conform with the grammar.

I have tried to come up with some fixed code below (no guarantees given, I haven't properly tested it). The changes I made are marked by comments. Also note that your `interpretCTREE` and related methods were written as if they would return an environment, but as this is not used, I omitted that part.

```
trait OpTree {
  sealed abstract class Ltree
  case class Var(x: String) extends Ltree
  case class Star(l: Ltree) extends Ltree

  sealed abstract class Etree
  case class Num(s: String) extends Etree
  case class Add(e1: Etree, e2: Etree) extends Etree
  case class Sub(e1: Etree, e2: Etree) extends Etree
  // typo fixed, "class" forgotten
  case class At(l: Ltree) extends Etree
  case class Amph(l: Ltree) extends Etree

  sealed abstract class Ctree
  case class Assign(l: Ltree, e: Etree) extends Ctree
  case class While(e: Etree, c: List[Ctree]) extends Ctree
  case class Print(l: Ltree) extends Ctree
}

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

object MiniC extends JavaTokenParsers with OpTree {
  // Parser
  def parse(source: String): List[Ctree] = 
    parseAll(prog, source) match {
    case Success(optree,_) => optree
    case _ => throw new Exception("Parse error!")
  }
  def prog: Parser[List[Ctree]] = commlist
  def commlist: Parser[List[Ctree]] = rep1sep(comm, ";")
  def comm: Parser[Ctree] = left~("="~>expr) ^^
                            { case l~e => Assign(l, e) } |
                            "print"~>left ^^
                            { case l => Print(l) } |
                            ("while"~>expr<~":")~(commlist<~"end") ^^
                            { case e~cs => While(e, cs) }
  // typo fixed "~" forgotten in "expr~op~expr"
  def expr: Parser[Etree] = wholeNumber ^^ (Num(_)) |
                            "("~>expr~op~expr<~")" ^^
                            { case e1~"+"~e2 => Add(e1, e2)
                              case e1~"-"~e2 => Sub(e1, e2) } |
                              left ^^ (At(_)) |
                             "&"~>left ^^ (Amph(_))
  def left: Parser[Ltree] = ident ^^ (Var(_)) |
                            "*"~>left ^^ (Star(_))
  def op: Parser[String] = "+" | "-"

  //Interpreter
  // new: fix some memory size (for test purposes)
  val MEMORY_SIZE = 16
  val memory = new Array[Int](MEMORY_SIZE)
  // new: represents first unused memory address
  var allocatedMemorySize = 0
  var env = Map.empty[String, Int]
  // new: simple memory allocation
  def allocateMemory(variableName : String) {
    env += (variableName -> allocatedMemorySize)
    allocatedMemorySize += 1
  }
  def interpretPTREE(p: List[Ctree]) {
    interpretCLIST(p)
  }
  def interpretCLIST(cs: List[Ctree]) { 
    for(c <- cs) interpretCTREE(c)
  }
  def interpretCTREE(c: Ctree) {
    c match {
      case Assign(l, e) => 
        // new: allocate memory for variables if necessary
        l match {
          case Var(x) => if (!env.contains(x)) allocateMemory(x)
          case _ => 
        }
        // new: store evaluated expression at evaluated address
        memory(interpretLTREE(l)) = interpretETREE(e)
      // new: handling print
      case Print(l) => 
        println(memory(interpretLTREE(l)))
      // new: handling while properly
      case While(e, cs) =>
        while (interpretETREE(e) != 0)
          interpretCLIST(cs)
    }
  }
  def interpretETREE(e: Etree): Int = e match {
    case Num(s) => s.toInt
    case Add(e1, e2) => interpretETREE(e1) + interpretETREE(e2)
    case Sub(e1, e2) => interpretETREE(e1) - interpretETREE(e2)
    // new: at returns the value that is stored in memory at the address represented by l
    case At(l) => memory(interpretLTREE(l))
    // new: amph returns the address that is represented by l
    case Amph(l) => interpretLTREE(l)
  }
  // new: evaluates l to memory address it represents
  def interpretLTREE(l: Ltree): Int = l match {
    case Var(x) => if (env.contains(x)) 
                     env(x)
                   else 
                     throw new Exception("Error: " + x + " is undefined.")
    case Star(l) => val memoryLocation = interpretLTREE(l)
                    if (0 <= memoryLocation && memoryLocation < MEMORY_SIZE)
                      memory(memoryLocation)
                    else
                      throw new Exception("Error: " + l + " is out of memory bounds.")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {
      val source = args(0)
      println("input : " + source)
      val optree = parse(source)
      println("optree : " + optree)
      interpretPTREE(optree)
      // new: nicer printing of memory
      println("final memory : " + (memory mkString ","))
      println("final namespace : " + env)
    }
    catch { case e: Exception => println(e)}
  }
}
```

Finally, here's a simple test program calculating Fibonacci numbers

```
scala MiniC "i = 5; x = 1; y = 1; print x; while i: i = (i - 1); z = y; y = (x + y); x = z; print x end; print y"
```

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, but I think there might be a small problem here. Testing with Fibonacci numbers runs just fine, but testing with arguments of
    
    "y = 4; z = &y; x = (7 + *z); *z = (y + 1)",
    
it does not give expected memory results. The expected final memory results are 5, 0, 11, but it gives 4, 5, 7.

Comment: Here are the explanations. 
    y=4; 
    z=&y; #store in z's cell the location named by y# 
    x = (7 + *z); #add 7 to the int stored at the location stored in z's location and store the sum in the location named by x# 
    *z = (y + 1) #add 1 to the int y's cell and store the sum at the location saved in z's location#

Comment: Sorry for I didn't mention pointer part of C language, but I want you to consider mentioned above.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, there was a stupid mistake in my program, I now fixed it in `interpretLTREE` the `case Star(l)` should of course return `memory(memoryLocation)` and not just `memoryLocation`.